# Java: PrintStream to String?

Tags: java, string, printstream

I have a function that takes an object of a certain type, and a `PrintStream` to which to print, and outputs a representation of that object. How can I capture this function's output in a String? Specifically, I want to use it as in a `toString` method.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Use a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) as a buffer:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final String utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();
    try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos, true, utf8)) {
        yourFunction(object, ps);
    }
    String data = baos.toString(utf8);
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the PrintStream to free all resources.

Comment: Use `new String(baos.toByteArray(), java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` available since **1.7**, it doesn't throw

Comment: @tobr certainly a good rule of thumb, but [`ByteArrayOutputStream.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#close--) "*has no effect*", as there are no resources to free besides the backing array which will be dealt with by the garbage collector.

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream` has `toString(String charsetName)`, but only accept String argument. Also note that ByteArrayOutputStream is **synchronized**, which    probably is not desirable

Comment: Both the `PrintStream` constructor and the `baos.toString` method now support the `Charset` objects directly, so there is no more need to convert `UTF_8` to `UTF_8.name()` first... I recommend adding `import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;` so you can use `UTF_8` directly as a value.

Answer (score 36):

You can construct a PrintStream with a ByteArrayOutputStream passed into the constructor which you can later use to grab the text written to the PrintStream.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);
...
String output = os.toString("UTF8");
```

Comment: Note that `toString("UTF8")` should be `toString("UTF-8")`

Answer (score 13):

Why don't you use a StringWriter with a PrintWriter?

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);
out.println("Hello World!");
String output = writer.toString();
```

Comment: Apart from top rated answer this one doesn't bother you with charsetName.

Comment: This won't work. You cannot pass the PrintWriter into a function which only takes a PrintStream as argument, which was what the question was about.

Comment: I gave it as a suggestion on replacing the PrintStream. It's usually a good choice. If you must use a PrintStream then this i definitely not a choice.

(I'm not sure why someone would vote -1 on this.. it still technically a viable option in most cases :) )

Answer (score 8):

A unification of previous answers, this answer works with Java 1.7 and after. Also, I added code to close the Streams.

```
final Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos, true, charset.name());
yourFunction(object, ps);
String content = new String(baos.toByteArray(), charset);
ps.close();
baos.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this question might help you:
[Get an OutputStream into a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216894/get-an-outputstream-into-a-string)

Subclass OutputStream and wrap it in PrintStream

Answer (score -4):

Define and initialize a Scanner variable named inSS that creates an input string stream using the String variable myStrLine.

Ans:
    Scanner inSS = new Scanner(myStrLine);