# Java equivalent to python's "with"

Tags: java, python, with-statement

Python has a nice feature: the "with" statement.  It's useful for making global changes that affect all code called within the statement.

e.g. you could define a class CapturePrintStatements to capture all print statements called within the "with"

```
with CapturePrintStatements() as c:
    print 'Stuff Done'
print 'More Stuff Done'
assert c.get_text() == 'Stuff Done'
```

Is there an equivalent in Java?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Mohammed noted, you can use try-with-resources. In this case, you want to have your own resource, and it is not really difficult to do.

### Creating an auto-closeable class

First, your class should implement `AutoCloseable`:

```
public class CaptureOutput implements AutoCloseable {
```

When constructing this class, you should

- store the old `System.out`,
- create a `PrintStream` to replace it (cf. [Java: PrintStream to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760668/287976)) and
- replace the default stream with `System.setOut()`.

Here is how we do it

```
    public CaptureOutput() {
        this.stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        this.out = System.out;

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(stream));
    }
```

The secret is the `AutoCloseable.close()` method: you just undo your replacement there:

```
    public void close() throws Exception {
        System.setOut(this.out);
    }
```

Finally, you need a method to retrieve the content:

```
    public String getContent() {
        return this.stream.toString();
    }
```

### Using try-with-resources

Done that, just pass the `CaptureOutput` to the `try` clause. The code below, for example...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String content = null;

    System.out.println("This will be printed");

    try (CaptureOutput co = new CaptureOutput()) {
        System.out.println("EXAMPLE");

        content = co.getContent();
    }

    System.out.println("This will be printed, too.");

    System.out.println("The content of the string is " + content);
}
```

...will result on this:

```
This will be printed
This will be printed, too.
The content of the string is EXAMPLE
```

### Scope issues

Note that we do not call `co.getContent()` at the last line. It is not possible because, unlike Python, the `co` variable is scoped inside the `try` clause. Once the `try` block finishes, it is gone.[1] That's why we get the value from inside the block.

Not that elegant, right? A solution may be to give the BAOS to the `CaptureOutput` constructor:

```
    public CaptureOutput(ByteArrayOutputStream stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
        this.out = System.out;

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(this.stream));
    }
```

Now, we just use the stream later:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("This will be printed");

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try (CaptureOutput co = new CaptureOutput(stream)) {
            System.out.println("EXAMPLE");
        }

        System.out.println("This will be printed, too.");

        System.out.println("The content of the string is " + stream.toString());
    }
```

(Also, it is not possible to create the `CaptureOutput` variable before the `try`. That makes sense: `AutoCloseable` objects are supposed to be "closed" after their use. What's the use of a closed file, after all? Our use case is a bit different from that, so we have to rely on alternatives.)

### The full classes

And here are the full classes:

- `CaptureOutput.java`:

  ```
  import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
  import java.io.PrintStream;

  public class CaptureOutput implements AutoCloseable {

      private ByteArrayOutputStream stream;
      private PrintStream out;

      public CaptureOutput(ByteArrayOutputStream stream) {
          this.stream = stream;
          this.out = System.out;

          System.setOut(new PrintStream(this.stream));
      }

      public CaptureOutput() {
          this(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
      }

      @Override
      public void close() throws Exception {
          System.setOut(this.out);
      }

      public String getContent() {
          return this.stream.toString();
      }

  }
  ```
- `Main.java`:

  ```
  import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

  public class Main {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          System.out.println("This will be printed");

          ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

          try (CaptureOutput co = new CaptureOutput(stream)) {
              System.out.println("EXAMPLE");
          }

          System.out.println("This will be printed, too.");

          System.out.println("The content of the string is " + stream.toString());
      }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 10):

[try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is its Java equivalent, and is available in Java 7 and up.

That gives you the possibility to work with resources that need to be explicitly closed, without worrying about closing them. For the example:

**Before Java7:**

```
InputStream input = null;

try {
    input = new FileInputStream("myFile.txt");

} finally {
    if(input != null){
        input.close();
    }
}
```

**Java 7 & up:**

```
try(FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("myFile.txt")) {
    // Do something with the InputStream
}
```

This is the ***try-with-resources*** construct. When the execution flow will go out of the `try` block, the `FileInputStream` will be **closed automatically**. This is due to the fact that `FileInputStream` implements the `AutoCloseable` interface.