# Android FTP download exception (file not found)

Tags: android, ftp

I am trying to retrieve a file via FTP but I am getting the following error in LogCat:
java.io.FileNotFoundException :/config.txt (read-only file system)

I have verified that the file exists on the server, and I can read it by double clicking it in a web browser.

Can anyone help please? Here is the code I am using:

```
 FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
 FileOutputStream fos = null;

 try {
     client.connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
     client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
     client.login("user", "pass");

     //
     // The remote file to be downloaded.
     //
     String filename = "config.txt";
     fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);

     //
     // Download file from FTP server
     //
     client.retrieveFile("/" + filename, fos);
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
     try {
         if (fos != null) {
             fos.close();
         }
         client.disconnect();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: Are you using the same credentials for your app and your FTP test? It's possible the server is presenting different file structures. What do you see in a full-up FTP client like FileZilla?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save files on the root of the phone. Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`to get an file object of the SD card's directory and save the file there. Maybe create a directory for it. To do that you need the permission `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Sample code:

```
try {
    File external = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String pathTofile = external.getAbsolutePath() + "/config.txt";
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(pathTofile);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't really need to save this file, I only need to read the contents. Is it possible to download the file via FTP, read the contents and then discard the file?

Comment: You can use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of a `FileOutputStream`. If you are only interested in reading text files you can create a `String` from it. See this question: [Get an OutputStream into a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216894/get-an-outputstream-into-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read the file in, but you have created an `OutputStream`, you need to create an `inputStream` and then read the file from that input stream.

Here is a great article, with come code that is very helpful. This should get you headed in the right direction.

http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml

I hope this helps!

Best of luck