# Test java programs that read from stdin and write to stdout

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I am writing some code for a programming contest in java. The input to the program is given using stdin and output is on stdout. How are you folks testing programs that work on stdin/stdout? This is what I am thinking:

Since System.in is of type InputStream and System.out is of type PrintStream, I wrote my code in a func with this prototype:

```
void printAverage(InputStream in, PrintStream out)
```

Now, I would like to test this using junit. I would like to fake the System.in using a String and receive the output in a String.

```
@Test
void testPrintAverage() {

    String input="10 20 30";
    String expectedOutput="20";

    InputStream in = getInputStreamFromString(input);
    PrintStream out = getPrintStreamForString();

    printAverage(in, out);

    assertEquals(expectedOutput, out.toString());
}
```

What is the 'correct' way to implement getInputStreamFromString() and getPrintStreamForString()?

Am I making this more complicated than it needs to be?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782178/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-inputstream-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216894/get-an-outputstream-into-a-string can help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [JUnit testing with simulated user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415728/junit-testing-with-simulated-user-input)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
String string = "aaa";
InputStream stringStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes())
```

`stringStream` is a stream that will read chars from the input string.

```
OutputStream outputStream = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
// .. writes to printWriter and flush() at the end.
String result = outputStream.toString()
```

`printStream` is a `PrintStream` that will write to the `outputStream` which in turn will be able to return a string.

Comment: Did you mean PrintStream instead of PrintWriter?

Comment: Yes. i misread the question in the beginning as needing a PrintWriter

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: Sorry I misread your question.

Read with scanner or bufferedreader, The latter is much faster than the former.

```
Scanner jin = new Scanner(System.in);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(System.in);
```

Write to stdout with print writer. You can also print directly to Syso but this is slower.

```
System.out.println("Sample");
System.out.printf("%.2f",5.123);

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
out.print("Sample");
out.close();
```

Comment: You can't pass `System.in` into a BufferedReader. You need to wrap it in an `InputStreamReader` first.

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing some code for a programming contest in java. The input to the program is given using stdin and output is on stdout. How are you folks testing programs that work on stdin/stdout?

Another way to send characters to `System.in` is to use `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream`.  Maybe something like the following:

```
PipedInputStream pipeIn = new PipedInputStream(1024);
System.setIn(pipeIn);

PipedOutputStream pipeOut = new PipedOutputStream(pipeIn);

// then I can write to the pipe
pipeOut.write(new byte[] { ... });

// if I need a writer I do:
Writer writer = OutputStreamWriter(pipeOut);
writer.write("some string");

// call code that reads from System.in
processInput();
```

On the flip side, as mentioned by @Mihai Toader, if I need to test `System.out` then I do something like:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(baos));

// call code that prints to System.out
printSomeOutput();

// now interrogate the byte[] inside of baos
byte[] outputBytes = baos.toByteArray();
// if I need it as a string I do
String outputStr = baos.toString();

Assert.assertTrue(outputStr.contains("some important output"));
```