# display the output-stream of a Process returned by Runtime.exec()

Tags: java, outputstream, runtime.exec

How do I print to stdout the output string obtained executing a command?

So `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` would return a `Process`, and by calling `getOutputStream()`, I can obtain the object as follows, but how do I display the content of it to stdout?

`OutputStream out = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls").getOutputStream();`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to get the output from process, and for that you should get the `InputStream`.

```
InputStream is = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls").getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader (isr);

String line;
while((line = buff.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.print(line);
```

You get the `OutputStream` when you want to write/ send some output to Process.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the stream to string as discussed in [Get an OutputStream into a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216894/get-an-outputstream-into-a-string) and simply use Sysrem.out.print()