# Unable to intercept and manipulate HttpServletResponse in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a requirement to `Base64` decode every JSON request payload that my Spring Boot service receives. The JSON payload would have been `Base64` encoded at the client before posting using the HTTP `POST` method. Further, I also need to `Base64` encode the JSON response before presenting to the calling client application.

I am required to reduce boilerplate code by using handler interceptors.
I have already achieved the request/incoming leg of the operation by the use of interceptors but is yet to achieve this for the response leg.
I have posted the code snippets below. The code to intercept the response and base64 encode it is in the postHandle method of the interceptor class.

What am I doing wrong here?

Interceptor Class:

```
public class Base64ResponseEncodingInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {   
    private static final String DECODED_REQUEST_ATTRIB = "decodedRequest";
    private static final String POST = "POST";


    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView arg3) throws Exception {
          try {
              if (POST.equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
                    CharResponseWrapper res = new CharResponseWrapper(response);
                    res.getWriter();
                    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(res.toString().getBytes());
                    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(response.getHeader(ENCODED_RESPONSE_ATTRIB).getBytes());
                    response.getWriter().write(new String(encoded));
              }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
          }
    }


    // preHandle and afterCompletion methods
    // Omitted 
}
```

The `CharResponseWrapper` Class used above:

```
public class CharResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    protected CharArrayWriter charWriter;

    protected PrintWriter writer;

    protected boolean getOutputStreamCalled;

    protected boolean getWriterCalled;


    public CharResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        charWriter = new CharArrayWriter();
    }


    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        if (getWriterCalled) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("getWriter already called");
        }
        getOutputStreamCalled = true;
        return super.getOutputStream();
    }


    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            return writer;
        }
        if (getOutputStreamCalled) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("getOutputStream already called");
        }
        getWriterCalled = true;
        writer = new PrintWriter(charWriter);
        return writer;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = null;
        if (writer != null) {
            s = charWriter.toString();
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

JavaConfig Class where Interceptor is registered:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = BaseRepositoryBean.class, basePackages = "")
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.companyname", "com.companyname.productname"})
public class RestConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


      @Override
      public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new Base64ResponseEncodingInterceptor());
      }

}
```

The Controller Class, where the Interceptor is used (Only the working request leg is shown here):

```
@Autowired
HttpServletRequest request;

String decodedRequest = null;

@ModelAttribute("decodedRequest")
public void getDecodedParam(){
    decodedRequest = (String) request.getAttribute("decodedRequest");
}
```

The code in the `postHandle` method does not work. It is either the `HttpServletResponse` is `null` or I get an exception message:

> getOutputStream already called

**Update: Work around solution to reading the response directly in the ResponseBodyAdvice**
In the Controller Class, I added the following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/ipmanager")
public class IPProfileRestController extends AbstractRestController {

    @Autowired
    HttpServletResponse response;

   String encodedResponse = null;

   @ModelAttribute("encodedResponse")
    public void getEncodedResponse(){
       response.setHeader("encodedResponse", StringUtils.EMPTY);
    } 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/time", method = { RequestMethod.POST }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE }, consumes = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public @ResponseBody String saveAccessClientTime(@RequestBody String ecodedRequest) {

        // Some code here

        String controllerResponse = prettyJson(iPProfileResponse);
        response.setHeader("encodedResponse", controllerResponse);
        return controllerResponse;
    }
}
```

I have the following in the **ResponseBodyAdvice**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class Base64EncodedResponseBodyAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, 
                            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body,
                                  MethodParameter returnType,
                                  MediaType selectedContentType,
                                  Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType,
                                  ServerHttpRequest request,
                                  ServerHttpResponse response) {

        String body1 = StringUtils.EMPTY;
        // Encode the response and return

        List<String> listOfHeaderValues = response.getHeaders().get("encodedResponse");

        body1=new String(Base64.encodeBase64(listOfHeaderValues.get(0).getBytes()));

        return body1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [Spring MVC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) states:

> the `postHandle` method of `HandlerInterceptor` is not always ideally
>   suited for use with `@ResponseBody` and `ResponseEntity` methods. **In such
>   cases an `HttpMessageConverter` writes to and commits the response
>   before `postHandle` is called which makes it impossible to change the
>   response**, for example to add a header. Instead an application can
>   implement `ResponseBodyAdvice` and either declare it as an
>   `@ControllerAdvice` bean or configure it directly on
>   `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`.

With that being said:

> What am I doing wrong here?

Since the response has been already committed, you can't change it. In order to change the response you should register a [`ResponseBodyAdvice<T>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html) and put your response encoding logic there:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class Base64EncodedResponseBodyAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, 
                            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body,
                                  MethodParameter returnType,
                                  MediaType selectedContentType,
                                  Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType,
                                  ServerHttpRequest request,
                                  ServerHttpResponse response) {

        // Encode the response and return
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ali. If I annotate with @ControllerAdvice, do I need to register it in the JavaConfig class like for the Interceptor for the request leg? I will quickly test this as soon as I can and revert with the results. Thanks.

Comment: No there is no need for registration, as long as it's scannable

Comment: Hello Ali, I have slotted this in and it will work. I was able to override the expected http response by sending a String object that was printed out in postman as the response. My challenge now, is the best way to access my response payload as string, so that I can base64 encode before presenting it to the client. response.getBody() only returns an OutputStream. Do you have any snippet for retrieving the payload body from ServerHttpResponse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216894/get-an-outputstream-into-a-string

Comment: I couldn't retrieve the data from the http response using the link above but I used a work around through setting a key in the response headers and assigning the response data to it within the Controller. In the ResponseBodyAdvice<Object>, I then read this value and Base64 encoded it. I will update my question above with the solution, and mark your answer as correct but I will still be interested in being able to read the Http response for the data rather than storing it in the response headers. Thank you very much, Ali

Comment: If all your controllers are returning `String`s, then you're better off defining a `ResponseBodyAdvice<String>` instead of `ResponseBodyAdvice<Object>`

Answer (score 0):

If your method is returning `ResponseEntity<T>` then write  this code in `postHandle()` method of your `HandlerInterceptor`:

eg. `response.addHeader("jwt_token", "kajdlakjd");`

it will work!!