# elasticsearch: convert StreamOutput to String

Tags: java, elasticsearch, java-stream

I'm overriding [`FilterClient`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.3.0/org/elasticsearch/client/FilterClient.html) so I can see incoming requests. I'd like some way to get a `String` representation of the [`ActionRequest`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.3.0/org/elasticsearch/action/ActionRequest.html) that's passed in. `ActionRequest` let's you write to a [`StreamOuput`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.3.0/org/elasticsearch/common/io/stream/StreamOutput.html), which is an Elasticsearch type that is a subclass of [`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html?is-external=true). This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216894/get-an-outputstream-into-a-string) shows how to convert `OutputStream` to a String, but I'm forced to use `StreamOuput` due to the `FilterClient` API.

How do I get a String representation of `ActionRequest` or at least a readable version that will show me useful information about the request? (Calling `ActionRequest.toString` calls `Object.toString`, which is not good enough for me.)

Comment: `StreamOuput` extends `OutputStream` so can't you just use it as an `OutputStream`?

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion. The SO post I linked to suggests using `ByteArrayOutputStream`. But you can't use `ByteArrayOutputStream` where `StreamOutput` is expected. Perhaps you can include a bit of code in a solution so I can understand.

Answer (score 5):

`StreamOutput` is an abstract class which has a subclass called `OutputStreamStreamOutput`. The latter is basically a wrapper around an `OutputStream`, so you'd create an instance that wraps a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then use it in the `ActionRequest.writeTo()` call.

```
// in your override doExecute method, add this:
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStreamStreamOutput osso = new OutputStreamStreamOutput(baos);

request.writeTo(osso);
String requestAsString = baos.toString("UTF-8");
```

Comment: This looks close to what I need, but I'm getting a bunch of �s in the output. I think it's outputting the correct request field names but the values are all gibberish. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe the content you're getting is binary and not textual... or simply not encoded in UTF-8

Comment: Is there a specific flag/configuration where the encoding of Elasticsearch requests is set?

Comment: Can you tell which request you're intercepting?

Comment: The request could be a bunch of different request types, including `SearchRequest`, `BulkRequest`, `MultiGetRequest`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @lf215 no he means that how the content that is sent may not only be simple text - Looking at the implementation of BulkRequest(writeTo Method) they write a single bytes representing the Type of request in the stream and may do the same for the fields - so if you assume the whole request is just a UTF8 String, then the resulting string may be offset from the correct output

Comment: Yes, that's right, the request classes have their own protocol in `writeTo` and `readFrom` and that's not necessarily a string, but integers, boolean, etc