# How can I serialize and deserialize a JVM object to a String?

Tags: java, scala, serialization

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize an object to a String.  (A byte array doesn't work for my needs.)

I have this code:

```scala
inline def serialize(o: Object): String = 
  val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  val oos  = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)
  oos.writeObject(o)
  val bytes = baos.toString(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
  baos.close
  oos.close
  bytes

inline def deserialize(b: String): Object = 
  val bytes = b.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
  val bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
  val ois  = new ObjectInputStream(bais)
  val ret = ois.readObject()
  bais.close
  ois.close
  ret
```

This seems like it should work but I get this error when run (deserialization):

```
[info] running co.blocke.dotty_reflection.RunMe
[error] (run-main-3) java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[error]     at co.blocke.dotty_reflection.RunMe.main(RunMe.scala)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[error] Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF
[error]     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:877)
[error]     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
[error]     at co.blocke.dotty_reflection.RunMe$.<init>(RunMe.scala:11)
[error]     at co.blocke.dotty_reflection.RunMe$.<clinit>(RunMe.scala)
[error]     at co.blocke.dotty_reflection.RunMe.main(RunMe.scala)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You might want to add scala and dotty tags to this

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216894/get-an-outputstream-into-a-string

Comment: Why not using a **JSON**, **CSV**, **XML**, **Protobuf** or any othe real serialization format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
val bytes = baos.toString(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

This won't work like you'd like it to. Instead, try using Base64 Encoder/Decoder. That should work